# Ошибка при компиляции и линковке map-reduce программы

Tags: g++, map-reduce, solaris, компиляция, c++

Решил откомпилировать программу согласно [Hadoop Tutorial 2.2 -- Running C++ Programs on Hadoop](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop). Использовал уже другой Makefile

```
CC = g++  
HADOOP_INSTALL = /export/hadoop-1.0.1  
PLATFORM = Linux-i386-32  
CPPFLAGS = -m32 -I$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/include

parindex: hadoopc++.cpp  
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -Wall -L$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/lib -lhadooppipes \
    -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o $@
```

и получил другую ошибку

> `g++ -m32 -I/export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/include hadoopc++.cpp -Wall -L/export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib -lhadooppipes \
> -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o parindex
> ld: fatal: file /usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/crtbegin.o; section [7].eh_frame and file /export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib/libhadooppipes.a(HadoopPipes.o); section [1269].eh_frame have incompatibile attributes and cannot be merged into a single output section 
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
> *** Error code 1 
> make: Fatal error: Command failed for target`parindex'`

В случае компиляции командой

> `g++ -m32 -I/export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/include -L/export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -o parindex hadoopc++.cpp`

получаю ошибку

> `Undefined first referenced symbol in file
> PQconnectdb                         /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
> Traverser(char const*)              /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
> PQstatus                            /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
> HadoopPipes::runTask(HadoopPipes::Factory const&) /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
> HadoopUtils::toString(int)          /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
> HadoopUtils::splitString(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) /var/tmp//ccG4aGRr.o
> ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to parindex
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Еще с десяток таких вопросов, и мы обязательно разберемся.

Answer (score 1):

[@ivan31](/users/4705/ivan31), вот это

```
ld: fatal: file /usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/crtbegin.o
```

а именно **i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/crtbegin.o** навевает мысли о том, что Вы смешали объектники из разных систем.

Например в линукс поставили либы соляриса.

Comment: @avp, вообще-то уменя solaris.

Comment: Тогда вот это

/export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/**Linux-i386-32/lib/libhadooppipes.a**

несовместимо с солярисом.

У Вас раньше метка linux была, а вообще поконкретней описывайте в чем работаете.

Comment: @avp, этот файл надо удалить или создать папку, которая содержит только so-файлы (правильно ли я понял, что файлы с расширением .a несовместимы с solaris) из папки /export/hadoop-1.0.1/c++/Linux-i386-32/lib/?

Comment: @ivan31, я думаю вам нужно найти эту библиотеку (libhadooppipes.a, а также все остальные)  **для соляриса** и установить их.

После этого все должно заработать.

--

Если не найдете попробуйте собрать все их у себя из исходников (где это все брать - не знаю).

Comment: @avp, а ошибки в случае компиляции второй командой тоже вызваны этой же причиной? И еще все-таки уточню один момент - файлы с расширением .a несовместимы с солярисом?

Comment: Несовместимы не файлы с расширением .a (в солярисе полно таких своих), а их содержимое, точнее формат объектных модулей, которые находятся в *.a

Пограмма `ld` (линкер) сообщила Вам об этом:

`/lib/libhadooppipes.a(HadoopPipes.o); section [1269].eh_frame **have incompatibile attributes** and cannot be merged into a single output section`